# How to compile VB.net in linux in monodevel?

Tags: vb.net, mono

I have a 500 line code that I wrote in vb net when I had windows.

In the meantime, I switched to Ubuntu. I can do only vb.net. I tried mono develop but it is so painful because it says `console.writeline` is not a command, or `application.commandlineargs` is invalid.

I tried installing packages available for mono for those commands and `system.console` did not work even though the package was included.

Comment: .NET core? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/

Comment: I found an article, [Why doesn't Console.WriteLine work in MonoDevelop since it's written in C#?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1023544/why-doesnt-consolewriteline-work-in-monodevelop-si.html), which suggest to me that you need an `Imports System`.

Comment: Mono's VB support is well known to be experimental and incomplete (C#/F# are the focus), so if you seriously want to run something on Linux, use .NET Core, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/ and Visual Studio Code is more suitable a development environment.